# How do I remove app icons from the top bar in 17.10?

Tags: 17.10, indicator, panel, gnome-shell, notification-area

Moving from Unity to GNOME with no experience. So, how do I remove those apps icons (Steam, VLC etc.) from the top bar? Here are the icons that I'm talking about:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have steam installed, but in VLC I go to Tools -> Preferences and uncheck "Show systray icon".  Then exit and relaunch VLC.  The icon should no longer be there, at least it wasn't in my environment (Ubuntu 17.10).  Check steam for a similar option.